# eclipse customize colors of html tags

Tags: html, eclipse

I recently started using eclipse for coldfusion/html development and there's a MAJOR feature I greatly miss with eclipse and that's the html syntax coloring. Eclipse has ALL html tags the same color which isn't very helpful when I can have over 100 lines of html code and looking for something specific. I'm use to different colors for form tags, table tags, anchor tags, img tags, etc to make it much easier to find what I'm looking for.

Is there any way I can customize certain html tags (or any keyword for that matter) to be displayed as a different color?

Something like this is what I'm used to and would LOVE eclipse to do.

[img: example of desired color coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZkoW.jpg)

Comment: What does have this feature?

Answer (score 0):

May be look for some plugin for this purpose, go to eclipse market place and search for it. Example: http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace: